# Entity Framework Migrations not being recognized while publishing ASP.NET WebApi project windows 10

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iis, asp.net-web-api, publish

I am new to this and I am trying to publish my web api project using visual studio where I am trying to publish my application to a local folder.
Everything works properly but Entity Framework Migrations shows an error,

dotnet tool install dotnet-ef
The tool package could not be restored
Tool 'dotnet-ef' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:
*You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version options to specify the version.

- A package by this name was found but it was not a .NET tool.
- The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
- You mistyped the name of the tool

I have tried different solutions but nothing worked so far

This is a code first Migration

I tried to install dotnet-ef globally but that did not work. I have installed it correctly with proper version (currently using 7.0.14) but this error still shows up

Comment: So, EF Classic or EF Core? It is two different libraries with own tooling.

Answer (score 0):

If everything you try fails, then you should check the following in Visual Studio:

Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings > Nuget Package Manager > Package Sources.

There you should have `nuget.org`, if not and you only have `Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages`, that is the problem. Then you need to add the package resource `nuget.org`.

[image]

Comment: It was already checked and still did not work

Comment: You can try clearing the NuGet cache and then try installing the Entity Framework Core tools again.

You can clear all caches with this command:
`nuget locals all --clear`